# Паттерны проектирования Банды Четырех. Класс Rect

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

В приложении В.5 "Паттернов проектирования" Банды Четырех написано "Класс Rect представляет прямоугольник, стороны которого параллельны осям координат. Прямоугольник определяется начальной вершиной и размерами, то есть шириной и высотой." У этого класса среди прочих есть 2 метода:

```
Point& Origin() const;
Point& Extent() const;
```

Я так понимаю, что класс должен содержать 2 члена-объекта класса Point. Но если мы возвращаем неконстантную ссылку на них, почему после объявления методов ставим const?

Comment: гмм... выглядит как ошибка... поидей они должны возвращать или по значению, или константную ссылку... посмотрел сейчас несколько изданий — вроде везде так... в гугле ни какой информации об ошибке тоже не нашёл... может за 25 с лишком лет ни кто в приложение просто не заглядывал (??)